# in query AND operator doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, operators

My database always returns that 1 row is found as a match for the condition that both, the `username` and `password` (here as `passhash`), are correct.

I can just type the correct `username` and no `password` or a random `password` and it will still return that it found 1 row which matches the condition.

```
                    $user = $_POST['username'];
                    $pass = $_POST['password'];

                    $phash = md5(sha1($pass+"salt123")+"salt123");

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND passhash='$phash'";

                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                    if ($count == 1)
                    {
                        echo "Welcome $user, you have successfully logged in!<br />";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    echo "username or password is incorrect!";
                    }
```

Comment: `+"salt123"` Doing math with that string doesn't make much sense. Maybe concatenation?

Comment: Please check your code, there might be something else running and returning the result

Comment: @Rizier123 Ops, I didn't want to do math at that point. It's a `+` for string in C# so i accidently put it as `+` there.

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: @GauravLad it is all the code i have besides the `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);` which i didn't put in this thread

Comment: Also I wouldn't recommend to mix OOP (`$conn->query($sql);`) and procedural (`mysqli_num_rows($result);`) style. Please don't use [md5](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) for password storage and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: @Rizier123 With `.` it works how it is supposed to be. thanks!